# Python - How to check if a string has wildcards or regex

Tags: python, regex, string, wildcard

I've got a field that is supposed to be `regex` entered by the user; however sometimes users are entering wildcards instead. I want to check if the input has wildcard and reject. Example:

**Valid (contains regex only)**

> s = 'abc1.*r.*'

> s = 'abc1.*r'

> s = 'abc1.r'

**Invalid (contains wildcard)**

> s = 'abc1*r*'

> s = 'abc1.*r*'

I've tried re.findall:

```
s = 'abc1.\*rr*.*' # String contains wildcard hence should be rejected
a = len(re.findall('\.\*', s))
b = len(re.findall('\*', s))
if a != b:
    print "reject"
```

Basically checking if number of .* and * are equal. If not, that means there is a '*' without a '.'

Is there a better, cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: But `abc1*r*` is a valid regex too, isn't it?

Comment: True, the question could be worded better. There is a function that matches this regex with further inputs from the user. Normally, 'abc4*test' should match 'abc44test' but this function doesn't match on it. It's some Java stuff im not too familiar with and I can't change how this function works.

Comment: So it's not that you want to reject _non-regexes_, you just want to reject the string if at least one `*` is after a non-dot?

Comment: Yes true, spot on.

Comment: It seems like the question is not just poorly worded - it's just not clear what you mean by a valid regex. Like @sweeper said, `abc1*r*` is a perfectly valid regex, it just means something completely different from `abc1.*r.*`. It allows for repeating `1` and `r` zero or more times, while the second one needs at least one `1` and `r`, but allows anything after it.

Comment: So, `s = 'abc(.)*r'` would not be ok, even though it's a perfectly valid regex? (because it doesn't have the period directly in front of the `*`?)

Comment: Apologies @sweeper - my comment was missing a `*`, typo on my part

Comment: Given that the OP asks for an easier way to do what the code in the question is already doing, I would say that should still be rejected. @Grismar

Comment: Agreed @sweeper - I suppose I was wondering if the problem OP is trying to solve is actually the whole problem they have, but you're right and your answer does do exactly what was asked, if that is what OP indeed needs.

Comment: On a tangent, any thoughts why the function doesn't accept *? From what I can see it is using standard Java import:

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException;

Comment: Just seeing the imports tells me almost nothing. I suggest you post a new question with the relevant Java code. You can post a link here so I can check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with this regex:

```
[^.]\*
```

This regex finds a non-dot character followed by a `*`. If this matches anywhere, then the regex should be rejected:

```
if re.search(r'[^.]\*', s):
    print("Rejected!")
```